# Count how many palindrome numbers are on the segment [1, 10 ** n] (n <100)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, palindrome

It is necessary to calculate how many palindrome numbers are on the segment [1, 10 ** n] (n <100).

```js
function f(n) {
    let res = 10 ** (parseInt(n / 2) + n % 2);
    return res - res / 10;
}

function countPalindromes(n) {
    let count = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        count += f(i);
    }
    return count;
}

for (let i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
    console.log(i, f(i), countPalindromes(i));
}
```

Problems:

1. Over time js returns the result in exponential form, and the result cannot be translated into a string.
2. Adding such large numbers into a column does not work
   And so, how can I count the number of palindromes in the segment [1, 10 ** n] (n <100)???

Comment: Try to find some recursive relations relatively to the value of `n`

Comment: How many palindromes have length `2k`?  How many have length `2k+1`?  Answer those, and the question becomes easy.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with a smaller problem first. How many `n` digit palindromic numbers exist?

If `n` is even, let the number be of the form `_ _ _ _ (midpoint) _ _ _ _`. Now, in the first digit, you can't fill 0, so you have 9 options (1-9). For the second digit to the `n/2`th digit, you can fill any of the digits in 0-9. Since we're dealing with palindromes, second half of the number will have the same digits as the first half. So, using basic counting, total number of `n` digit palindromes when `n` is even is `9*[10*10*...10 (n/2)-1 times] = 9 * 10^((n/2)-1)`

When `n` is odd, the analysis will be similar, but with two differences:

1. You have 10 choices (0-9) for the midpoint.
2. There are `(n-1)/2` digits on either side of the midpoint, where the first digit can't be 0.

Again, using basic counting, number of palindromes if `n` is odd = `9 (for first digit) * 10 (for midpoint) * 10^((n/2)-2) (the remaining digits) = 9 * (10^(n/2)-1)`, similar to the even case.

Thus, number of `n` digit palindromes = `9 * (10^(n/2)-1)` if `n` is greater than 1. After that, you just have to loop `n` from 2 to 100 to get the total count of palindromic numbers you need.

Answer (score -1):

<s>I'm not 100% sure, so correct me if I'm wrong.</s> It works, check the code at the bottom.

There should be two kinds of palindromes: ones with odd number of digits and ones with even number of digits. You can go from one palindrome to another (of the same kind) by appending and prepending the same digit to the first one. So...

Single-digit palindromes: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9.

For every single-digit palindrome, we can construct 10 3-digit palindromes:

000, 101, 202, ..., 010, 111, 212, ..., 898, 999.

Similarly, for every 3-digit palindromes, we can construct 10 5-digit palindromes.

`10 ** n` would have up to n-digit palindromes. Let's count:

10 ** 1 single-digit, 10 ** 2 3-digit, 10 ** 3 5-digit, ..., 10 ** ((n + 1) / 2) n-digit.

The same can be done for double-digit palindromes (00, 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99), to iteratively obtain palindromes with an even number of digits.

Then we need to drop the 'illegal' numbers - numbers starting with the digit 0.

---

It works. Yay!

```js
// Counting without creating the numbers
function getSmartCount(n) {
  let smartPalindromeCount = 0;
  let startingWithZeroCount = 0;
  for (let digits = 1; digits <= n; digits += 2) { // even digits
    const power = (digits + 1) / 2;
    smartPalindromeCount += 10 ** power;
    startingWithZeroCount += 10 ** (power - 1); // the zero-x-zero numbers
  }
  for (let digits = 2; digits <= n; digits += 2) { // odd digits
    const power = digits / 2;
    smartPalindromeCount += 10 ** power;
    startingWithZeroCount += 10 ** (power - 1); // the zero-x-zero numbers;
  }
  return smartPalindromeCount - startingWithZeroCount;
}

// Counting by creating the numbers
function getCountIteratively(n) {
  const singleDigitPalindromes = '0123456789'.split('');
  const doubleDigitPalindromes = singleDigitPalindromes.map(x => x + x);
  const palindromes = [...singleDigitPalindromes, ...doubleDigitPalindromes];
  const nestedPalindromes = [
    singleDigitPalindromes,
    doubleDigitPalindromes,
  ];
  for (let digits = 3; digits <= n; digits++) {
    const index = digits - 1;
    const extraPalindromes = [];
    const previousPalindromes = nestedPalindromes[index - 2];
    for (const previousPalindrome of previousPalindromes) {
      for (const character of singleDigitPalindromes) {
        const newPalindrome = character + previousPalindrome + character;
        extraPalindromes.push(newPalindrome);
        palindromes.push(newPalindrome);
      }
    }
    nestedPalindromes.push(extraPalindromes);
  }
  const legalPalindromes = palindromes.filter(palindrome => palindrome[0] !== '0');
  // console.log(legalPalindromes); // uncomment to see the numbers
  return legalPalindromes.length;
}

// Counting by checking every single number
function getCountByBruteForce(n) {
  const bruteForcePalindromes = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < 10 ** n; i++) {
    const leftToRight = i.toString();
    const rightToLeft = leftToRight.split('').reverse().join('');
    if (leftToRight === rightToLeft) {
      bruteForcePalindromes.push(i);
    }
  }
  // console.log(bruteForcePalindromes); // uncomment to see the numbers
  return bruteForcePalindromes.length;
}

for (let n = 2; n <= 5; n++) {
  console.log({
    n,
    smart: getSmartCount(n),
    byCreatingTheNumbers: getCountIteratively(n),
    bruteForce: getCountByBruteForce(n),
  });
}
```